# Facebook SDK Permission to access page message

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get a token to be able to read the data messages sent to my facebook page?

If I see here : `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#overview` there described :

`read_page_mailboxes` :
Enables your application to retrieve the Facebook Messages conversations for Pages. You must use a Page Access Token to do this. Conversations are retrieved by calling `/{page_id}/conversations` via the Graph API.

What should I do to get access to this?

Thanks

Comment: use the grap api explorer and then call the endpoint /{iduser}/account, this will give you the pages for which iduser is associated and the permissions, this will have an access token in the returned data. Save it and use it when ever doing an api call or just file_get_contents(api end point)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Do you mean like `php` `$response = $facebook->api('/my_acc_id/account');` ??

Comment: Yes you can do it..usually when u are wrting some api call for a fan page you may or may not have an app, so in that case you can use graph explorer to generate the token. But yes $response = $facebook->api('/my_acc_id/account'); is the api call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it, first you need to grab the page token for your page, I'm assuming that you've already logged the user with the scope **manage_pages** and **read_page_mailboxes**

To read/respond/delete messages you must be a **Full Admin, Content Creator or Moderator**

> Page admins have different roles, which is indicated by the perms
>   array returned as above. The functionality available to them is
>   decided based on the following perms values:

You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

Now for the code you need to get the page access token:

```
//get user accounts    
$pages = $this->facebook->api('/me/accounts');
foreach ($pages['data'] as $page) {
    if($page['id']==PAGE_ID_YOU_WANT){
        //the user is admin of the page you want
        $page_access_token = $page['access_token'];
        $page_conversations = $facebook->api('/PAGE_ID_YOU_WANT/conversations', 'GET', array('access_token' => $page_access_token));
    }

}
```

Comment: Spot on. Beat me to it. Props for mentioning the required rights for the user.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for your reply.....But after I try I get a blank screen. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: yes there is, a typpo on the line `$page_conversations = $facebook->api('{page_id}/conversations', 'GET', array('access_token' => $page_access_token));` didn't have a semi colon at the end of the line, I've added it

Comment: Still I get the same results..Is not no use `var_dump` or any others?

Comment: sure, put a `var_dump($page_conversations);` inside the if statement and add an else statement something like `else echo 'You're not admin!'`

Comment: @FabioAntunes Why do I get the error message `Not Admin`? I'm what makes this Page and still have full access to the fan page. Is there access I have to make before running this function?

Comment: You did authorize your app with the manage_page permissions? And are sure that you're using the right page_id?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48489/discussion-between-bertho-joris-and-fabio-antunes)